# Does Blender have a tool that does auto lip sync

Tags: animation

Detail: I don't use bones, I use 100% shape keys with my rigs to do facial expressions.

How do I make Blender do automatic lip sync?

Answer (score 1):

Blender has a plugin for automatic lip sync.  You can download it here: https://morevnaproject.org/2015/11/11/automatic-lipsync-animation-in-blender/  However, I do not know if it works with shape keys.